# Convert c++ crc16 calulation with polynomial to android java

Tags: java, android, c++, crc, crc16

I have the following c++ crc16 calculation "U16 Crc16"
I've tried every example to convert this to android Java.  Nothing has worked.

```
#define POLYNOM16 0xAC5E //  1.X15 + 0.X14 + 1.X13 + 0.X12 1010 A
                         //+ 1.X11 + 1.X10 + 0.X09 + 0.X08 1100 C
                         //+ 0.X07 + 1.X06 + 0.X05 + 1.X04 0101 5
                         //+ 1.X03 + 1.X02 + 1.X01 + 0.X00 1110 E
U16 Crc16(const void* data, S16 sizeofData)
{
    U16 Crc      = 0xFFFF;
    U16 ByteCnt = 0;
    U8 BitCnt   = 0;
    U16 Parity  = 0;
    if (sizeofData <= 0 || data == NULL) return 0;
    U8* ptr = (U8*)data;
    for ( ByteCnt = 0 ; ByteCnt < sizeofData ; ByteCnt ++)
    {
        Crc ^= *( ptr + ByteCnt);
        if( Crc == 0 ) Crc = 1;
        for ( BitCnt = 0; BitCnt <= 7 ; BitCnt ++)
        {
            Parity = Crc;
            Crc >>= 1;
            if ((Parity & 1) !=0 ) Crc ^= POLYNOM16;
        }
    }
    return(Crc);
}
```

Here's my latest java conversion try in two functions.

```
 public static int crc16_update(int crc, byte a,int poly)
{
    crc ^= ((a+128) & 0xff);
    for (int i = 0;  i < 8; ++i) {
        if ((crc & 1) != 0) {
            crc = ((crc >>> 1) ^ /*0xA001*/poly) & 0xffff;
        }
        else {
            crc = (crc >>> 1) & 0xffff;
        }
    }
    return crc;
}
public static byte[] crc16Miron(byte[] bytes, int poly)
{
    int crc = 0;
    for (byte b : bytes) {
        crc = crc16_update(crc, b, poly);
    }
    return new byte[]{(byte)(crc & 0x00FF),(byte)((crc & 0xFF00)>>8)};
    //org return (short) crc;
}
```

Here's a hex string of byte data, the top last two bytes "good" crc16.
373237393130000000000000000000004e4f4d3030343533372d430000000000303030313146000000000000000000000b060000010001012d6678025b437e0008b7e5  where b7e5 is the "good" crc16

Here's the same array without the two byte "good" crc16 because according to documentation I don't use the crc in the calc.                        373237393130000000000000000000004e4f4d3030343533372d430000000000303030313146000000000000000000000b060000010001012d6678025b437e0008

So. if you pass the second hex string as a byte[],  it should calculate b7e5 but it doesn't.

Comment: You're using different polynomials. Further, in the C++ code your `crc` starts as `0xffff`. In your Java code it starts as `0`.

Comment: Use MUCH SMALLER strings of bytes for your test input. If you don't get the same result for 2-byte strings, you won't get the same result for 100-byte strings. You can reason about the 2-byte strings much easier.

Comment: I pass in the polynomial 0xAC5E, because I saw so many different polynomials from all the examples.

I changed int crc = 0; to int crc = 0xFFFF, Thanks.

I have byte [] rrr hard coded to those long strings so I can "Trust" the b7e5 calculated.  Here's how its called:
byte [] cs = crc16Miron(rrr, 0xAC5E);

hmmm even with the FFFF fix it crc16Miron doesn't calculate "b7e5"

But Thanks.